# run ddclient as a service in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, ddclient

there is no description of how to do this on the [github wiki](https://github.com/wimpunk/ddclient/wiki) or [sourceforge wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/usage/) just how to

There is a file

```
/etc/default/ddclient

# Configuration for ddclient scripts
# generated from debconf on Thu Jul 27 17:32:33 ACST 2017
#
# /etc/default/ddclient

# Set to "true" if ddclient should be run every time DHCP client ('dhclient'
# from package isc-dhcp-client) updates the systems IP address.
run_dhclient="false"

# Set to "true" if ddclient should be run every time a new ppp connection is
# established. This might be useful, if you are using dial-on-demand.
run_ipup="false"

# Set to "true" if ddclient should run in daemon mode
# If this is changed to true, run_ipup and run_dhclient must be set to false.
run_daemon="true"

# Set the time interval between the updates of the dynamic DNS name in seconds.
# This option only takes effect if the ddclient runs in daemon mode.
daemon_interval="300"
```

If I go to

```
sudo systemctl edit --full  ddclient.service
```

a file is created with these parameters

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/ddclient
Description=LSB: Update dynamic domain name service entries
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
Before=shutdown.target
After=local-fs.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=network-online.target
After=systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
Wants=network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ddclient start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/ddclient stop
```

This doesn't run at boot though..? I can only get the service to start manually with either `sudo etc/init.d/ddclient start` or `sudo systemctl start ddclient.service`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `sudo update-rc.d ddclient enable`

Comment: Awesome thankyou, could you explain pls how you know that?

Comment: I noted running 
    **sudo systemctl edit --full  ddclient.service**
after breaks this service

Comment: Please note if you do not know what you are doing, do not edit configs you know nothing of. I know this by having run into the same issue years ago.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is no manual for systemd, how I'm I supposed to configure this service then?!

Comment: Open your terminal and run `man systemd`.

Comment: This worked in 18.04 as well.